# Is it safe to BAN ASN from Hosting providers?

Tags: security, botattack

I have some bot problem, i found their ASN and it comes from web hosting providers. Not ISP's. For example:

- Hetzner: AS24940
- Digital Ocean: AS14061
- AMAZON-AES: AS14618

**Is it safe to ban entire ASN's if they belong to hosting providers?** There's like 2 million IP's in these. I wouldn't like to ban legitimate visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Is it safe to ban entire ASN's if they belong to hosting providers?***

Yes.

These are not users. Assigned IP addresses are assigned in blocks that are either subscriber, such as DSL customers, or non-subscriber, such as web hosting. It is always safe to block non-subscriber blocks short of a search engine or other service you may actually want. For example, I routinely block traffic from link bots and site performance sites by blocking the entire assigned block(s) as well as web hosts that have a problem with hacked servers or host spam bots, scrapers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else reaching this question, in the future I would say it depends. For example, if your servers provide an API for thirdparty apps blocking an entire ASN might be a very bad idea.

Comment: Yeah - also if you are OK with people using proxies or VPN's this may block some providers of those.   Also its possible - albeit unlikely - that one of these providers is advertising traffic for an ISP.  (After all, it could be a good way of balancing incoming traffic with their outbound traffic)